Odoo 17: Styling Issue in Product Price List Report
I’m working on a custom report in Odoo 17 to generate a product price list. However, I’m encountering a styling issue in the generated report, as shown in the screenshot :
generated report 
In the screenshot:
Item (1) and (2) have similar image dimensions, but they appear inconsistent in terms of styling/layout.
<t t-set="product_image" t-value="p.product_id.image_1920 if p.product_id.is_product_variant else p.product_tmpl_id.image_1920"/>
<td style="width:10%;border-collapse: collapse;border: none;text-align: center;">
   <img t-attf-src="data:image/*;base64,{{product_image}}" style="width:60px !important; height:60px !important"/> 
</td>

I’ve already verified that:
The dimensions of the images for both items are the same.
The issue seems to arise in the way the table or images are rendered.
Could anyone help me understand why this inconsistency is happening or suggest how to fix the styling issue?
Thanks in advance for your assistance! Let me know if you need additional code or context.

Did you check it with "html" mode? If you have the same rendering problem you can inspect it and maybe found out the problem:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/backend/reports.html#reports-are-web-pages
